# different positioned columns css

Tags: jquery, css

There are some plugins to make pintrest style columns that are basically calculating where to place the divs with unique absolute positioning for every element. My design is more simple and I would think there should be a css3 solution...

Can you make every other column pushed down like 20px? The design is responsive so depending on browser size will depend on how many columns there are so I would not just want to wrap every column in a div and move it down...

http://jsfiddle.net/3eVHU/1/

```
$('.container div').each(function() {
        if($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            listInRow++;
        }
        else {
            listInRow++;   
        }
    });
```

so somehow in my fiddle I would need a way to calculate the number of divs in the first row only and position every other element / row downward just a bit just like in this pic below

[image]

Is there any way to do this simply or would I still need to use something like masonry or another pintrest style reproducing library?

Comment: You could use CSS columns with media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: I've never seen css columns so thanks for showing that! Although I looked around and I cannot target css columns so I wouldn't be able to target every other css column to move it down :( Thanks though!

Comment: Yes you are right. CSS column won't solve your problem, but it is a nice feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

BOOYA! Cant say how excited I was to find this. My calculation script wont work to find the number of elements on the first row which I need but it all works without any JS to at least position the elements!